# C++ CGI on Mac and MIDI access

Tags: c++, macos, cgi, midi

I am new to `Mac` development and particularly `CGI`. 
I have written a `C++` program that successfully sends `MIDI` messages via the `RtMIDI` library. 
I wanted to run this program via a client browser. 
I wrote a C++ program to send a text stream to the browser, following the CGI rules:

```
cout << "Content-type; ...
```

I built the project and ran it successfully after putting it in the `Apache` web server cgi directory. 
When I add a line to create a new `RtMidiOut` object, I get a message in my browser page indicating that the server encountered an internal error.
The `Apache` error log indicates that the server couldn't connect to com.apple.midiserver and that `CoreMIDI` will not be usable.

Am I trying to do something that is not possible via `CGI`? Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks, Richard.

Comment: Instead of testing your program in a browser, try to run it as a normal program, or run in a debugger in case there is a crash. And remember to always check for and handle errors.

Comment: it could be a problem with permissions. cgi programs are usually run with very few permissions.

Comment: Yes, it runs fine as a normal program. The issue is running it as a cgi bin. Thanks for the idea about permissions. I believe that this is my problem - now how to resolve it!